# Why is my computer so slow s:

Tags: memory, performance, cpu, desktop-computer, windows-10-preview

I've had this problem for so long and it's annoying me. Everyone says my computer is bad but I dont get it. on Runescape I get 4 FPS. On LoL my computer just crashes and Skyrim is insanely laggy and this is on lowest graphics. Ive tried installing Windows multiple of times. Im now on Windows 10 which seems to be faster than 7.

```
RAM: 8 GB
Processor: Pentium(R) Dual Core 3.20 Ghz
Graphic driver: Nvidia GeForce 9500 GT
Motherboard: Intel (not sure which one)
HDD: 500GB
```

It happens with anything. Eclipse, Intellij, Games, Browsers all go insanely slow. I highly doubt its a virus since it's like that even after reinstallation.

Dont know any sites to make a diagnostic of my system hardware and show you guys or whatever

Comment: Well lets try one more time then: your computer is bad...or at least very old.  That cpu is, at best, from 2009.  Yes, it's "fast", but compared to today, it's really not (a higher processing speed does not necessarily mean your cpu is faster).  RAM from that era is either slow DDR3 or fast DDR2 (which is slower than ddr3).  the HDD is very old at this point and is probably dying, and your gfx card is lackluster at best.  It's time for a new computer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the best computer expert but I would say your Processor isn't the best for a game like skyrim. Also Runescape and LoL may be laggy if your internet is bad. I would suggest checking background programs too that may be slowing your computer down.

Comment: thats what I was thinking but people comment that its good on reviews. also my internet is around 90bmps lol

Comment: have you tried searching for viruses and other things of the sort?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that can be done. Here's the process for clearing startup items. If you've never done this before you could potentially have dozens launching with your OS.

1. Start by doing a quick audit of your processes. Star the task manager (Right-click the task bar and click "Start Task Manager", then go to the 'Processes' tab. Write down how many processes are running as shown at the bottom left of the window. Now click the 'Show processes from all users' button and then note the number of processes again. Sort using the CPU column, and note any processes sucking up a lot of CPU. Do the same for memory.
2. Remove unnecessary startup items. Start > Run:'msconfig' > startup tab. Uncheck everything except your antivirus program, steam, and things you use daily, like Dropbox.
3. Uninstall old/unused programs. Start > Control Panel > Programs and Features. While you're in the Programs area, notice if you have two antivirus applications installed. This can cause issues. If there are two, toss the one you don't use and attempt a repair on the remaining one.
4. Restart and then check the running processes again.

Beyond that, if you don't see the improvement you're looking for, keep the Task Manager open while you go about using the computer. If you notice it being slow try to identify which process is causing issues by ordering them by CPU and Memory.

If you suspect malware you should ensure your antivirus definitions are up to date. See your AV software documentation (google) for instructions. If you use Norton because it came with the system I recommend tossing it and grabbing Comodo Internet Security. It's free and works well. Spybot is still good, and I always recomend Malwarebytes.

Note: If you have any questions about the items in the startup list, or on the processes tab, you can Google them. If you come across any that are just random letters, they're likely malware.

Answer (score 0):

Does the computer work "acceptably" when you're in the windows environment (web browser, browsing computer content, viewing documents - in word, office-like activities), and problems start only when playing games?

If yes then its possible that:

1. You have corrupted VGA drivers. Remove them completely (advanced driver options in the System), download newest version for the card you have and install them again
2. Your Graphics adapter is failing. Consider replacing. At least check with another one, if you have one or "can beg, borrow or steal" one from someone.
3. Your system overheats.

I'd still consider all the steps in Alex's Answer as well. He may be onto something too.